# How to treat missing & undefined properties as equivalent in Lodash's isEqualWith

Tags: javascript, lodash, equality

I'm fighting with a custom comparison functions for Lodash's [`_.isEqualWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqualWith). I'd like a function such that this is works:

```
const comparisonFunc = /* ...TBC... */

// Should be true:
_.isEqualWith({ a: undefined }, { }, comparisonFunc);

// Should still be false, as normal:
_.isEqualWith({ a: undefined }, { a: 123 }, comparisonFunc);

// Should still be false, as normal:
_.isEqualWith([undefined], [ ], comparisonFunc);
```

I.e. for any object in the comparison (recursively), properties set to `undefined` should be treated as if they didn't exist.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's possible. It seems like if the keys of the first two arguments don't match, then the method doesn't do a recursive comparison of all the values. You can either create all matching keys for both objects or write some other function to do the comparison instead.

Comment: so is it a flat level data, or the data can go upto any depth. the examples are just flat in data (object or array) but is the question for and depth?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee yes, any depth. It work recursively, like `isEqualWith` does normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not as simple as I'd like, but I found a solution for this:

```
const comparisonFunc = (a, b) => {
    if (_.isArray(a) || _.isArray(b)) return;
    if (!_.isObject(a) || !_.isObject(b)) return;

    if (!_.includes(a, undefined) && !_.includes(b, undefined)) return;

    // Call recursively, after filtering all undefined properties
    return _.isEqualWith(
        _.omitBy(a, (value) => value === undefined),
        _.omitBy(b, (value) => value === undefined),
        comparisonFunc
    );
}


// Should be true:
_.isEqualWith({ a: undefined }, { }, comparisonFunc); // = true

// Should still be false, as normal:
_.isEqualWith({ a: undefined }, { a: 123 }, comparisonFunc); // = false

// Should still be false, as normal:
_.isEqualWith([undefined], [ ], comparisonFunc); // = false
```

Happy to accept other answers if anybody has something simpler or better though :-)

Comment: Try avoiding `omitBy` instead use `pickBy`, the way you are doing it is right but too much of code and and not a simple one to read..

Comment: Unfortunately lodash `isEqualWith` is not capable to solve such question - it is not possible to handle inherited objects with undefined properties. If you are going to return `undefined` than you are loosing control of any child comparison.

Comment: @puchu isEqualWith always applies recursively, so you don't lose control of child comparison by returning `undefined`. With the above for example, `_.isEqualWith([{ a: undefined }], [{ }], comparisonFunc)` returns true, even though `undefined` is returned when the top-level array is encountered. This seems to work for me, do you have an example where it fails?

Comment: Sorry, I had wrong understanding of `isEqualWith`: it passes next object and array comparison to `customizer` once again.

Comment: For future visitors, here is a [link to the relevant docs](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/is-equal-with/). The first three cases in comparisonFunc work because when the comparison function returns undefined, the default is used (recursively).

Answer (score 0):

You can just check wheather is is an array or object and filter `undefined` members accordingly, and call recursively thats it.

```js
const comp = (a, b) => {
  var A, B,
      fn = v => !_.isUndefined(v),
      filter = _.isArray(a)  ? _.filter : _.pickBy;
 if (_.isObject(a)) {
  A = filter(a, fn)
  B = filter(b, fn)
 } else { return _.isEqual(a, b); } 

 if (_.keys(a).length === _.keys(A).length && _.keys(b).length === _.keys(B).length) {return}
 return _.isEqualWith(A, B, comp);
};

var a1 = [10, 10, undefined, undefined, 10],
    a2 = [undefined, undefined, 10, undefined, 10, undefined, 10],
    o1 = {x: 10, y:undefined, z: 20, v: a1}
    o2 = {x: 10, z: 20, v: a2};

console.log('a1 with a2: ', _.isEqualWith(a1, a2, comp));
console.log('o1 with o2: ', _.isEqualWith(o1, o2, comp));
console.log('a1 with o2: ', _.isEqualWith(a1, o2, comp));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Checking the key length and the return statement is there to identify wherher we have to travarse inside (we have removed undefined in last iteration) or we need to travarse it again (as we removed the undefined values in this iteration)

Answer (score 0):

The same as Tim Perry's answer, only with TypeScript and `lodash/fp`

```
function matchMissingWithUndefined(a: {}, b: {}) {
  const hasUndefined = _.includes(undefined);
  if (_.isPlainObject(a) && _.isPlainObject(b) && (hasUndefined(a) || hasUndefined(b))) {
    const onlyDefined = _.omitBy((value) => value === undefined);
    return _.isEqualWith(matchMissingWithUndefined, onlyDefined(a), onlyDefined(b));
  }
}

_.isEqualWith(matchMissingWithUndefined, { a: undefined }, { }); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

After omitting `null` values we should somehow bypass initial call to `customizer` without checking that object does not `includes` `null` values once again.

I've invented some sort of nice bike for such purpose:

```
const compareWithoutNullProperties = (a: any, b: any) =>
  isPlainObject(a) && isPlainObject(b)
    ? isEqualWith(
      omitBy(a, (value) => value == null),
      omitBy(b, (value) => value == null),
      (a: any, b: any, key?: number | string | symbol): boolean | undefined =>
        // Next initial call should be ignored.
        key != null ? compareWithoutNullProperties(a, b) : undefined,
    )
    : undefined;

const isEqualWithoutNullProperties = (a: any, b: any) =>
  isEqualWith(a, b, compareWithoutNullProperties);
```

Tests returning `true`:

```js
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: undefined }, {});
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: null }, {});
isEqualWithoutNullProperties([{ a: undefined }], [{}]);
isEqualWithoutNullProperties([{ a: null }], [{}]);
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: { a: undefined } }, { a: {} });
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: { a: null } }, { a: {} });
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: [{ a: undefined }] }, { a: [{}] });
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: [{ a: null }] }, { a: [{}] });
```

Tests returning `false`:

```js
isEqualWithoutNullProperties([undefined], []);
isEqualWithoutNullProperties([null], []);
isEqualWithoutNullProperties([undefined], [1]);
isEqualWithoutNullProperties([null], [1]);
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: undefined }, { a: 1 });
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: null }, { a: 1 });
isEqualWithoutNullProperties([{ a: undefined }], [{ a: 1 }]);
isEqualWithoutNullProperties([{ a: null }], [{ a: 1 }]);
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: { a: undefined } }, { a: { a: 1 } });
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: { a: null } }, { a: { a: 1 } });
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: [{ a: undefined }] }, { a: [{ a: 1 }] });
isEqualWithoutNullProperties({ a: [{ a: null }] }, { a: [{ a: 1 }] });
```